# Why is chrome.fileBrowserHandler API undefined when reading onExecute?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

### Overview

I'm writing a ChromeOS Files extension for encrypting files. For that I'm using the Google Chrome [chrome.fileBrowserHandler API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/fileBrowserHandler). When opening the Files context menu, I get an "Encrypt" option (`Open with… > Encrypt`):

[image: ChromeOS file manager with a right-click context menu open. The mouse is hovering over the extension menu icon "Encrypt My Files".]

### The issue I'm facing

The example code snipped provided [by the API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/fileBrowserHandler) does throw an `Uncaught TypeError`.

[image: The chrome://extension page with the developer settings turned on. The page returns one warning and one error with an uncaught TypeError.]

The error message written for accessibility:

```js
// Warning: Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
"service_worker": "background.js"

// Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onExecute')
// Context
// background.js
// Stack Trace
// background.js:3 (anonymous function)
chrome.fileBrowserHandler.onExecute.addListener((id, details) => {
```

Why am I facing the error message?

### Source Code

```js
// background.js
"use strict";

chrome.fileBrowserHandler.onExecute.addListener((id, details) => {
  if (id === "encrypt") {
    chrome.windows.create({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'),
      type: "popup"
    });
  }
});
```

```json
// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Encrypt My Files",
  "description": "Encrypt files natively on ChromeOS",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "permissions": ["fileBrowserHandler"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "file_browser_handlers": [
    {
      "id": "encrypt",
      "default_title": "Encrypt",
      "file_filters": [
        "filesystem:*.*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "120"
}
```

### Things I noticed

When specifying just a `console.log` statement in background.js, the extension can be turned on without any issues. Also, using a `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` in `background.js` (e.g. for context menus in web pages) works.

Comment: It's not compatible with ManifestV3 service worker.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your answer! Is there another way to get a solution for my problem without the chrome.fileBrowserHandler API?